# How to enter sub- and superscripts in Equation Editor in MS One Note?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, equation-editor

It is possible to enter complete script boxes with

[image]

but this way I will be required to retype all base formula. For example, suppose I wish to enter

[image]

If I already entered

(a-b)

and then select superscript, I will get

[image]

Is it possible to enter superscript only, without basis box?

Comment: are you saying you don't want an base at all, or do you want to start with one, and then add an exponent?

Comment: Want to start with one I have.

Answer (score 6):

Try placing a carat (^) in between the base and superscript, and then pressing the spacebar after you type the superscript. Parenthesis help define what you want included in the superscript.

Same method can be used for subscript, but using and underscore instead (_).

Comment: this is the best and fastest method!

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `=`

(Highlight characters you wish to format as superscript and then press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `=`)

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-Shortcuts-for-OneNote-2010-7504CF95-1A03-40D9-9544-090901174620

Comment: yep, this worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

To raise a term you have already typed, Highlight the term. then go to the equation editor -> Scripts -> superscript. That will make the highlighted term the base.

Otherwise you can drag or cut and paste the base term into the lower dashed box.

Comment: It does not work this way for me. If I highlight term, it disappears once superscript selected.

Comment: hmmm, you are right, it works differantly in onenote than it does in word. you will have to cut/paste or drag the term into the bottom dashed box.

Comment: This is what I am doing all the time and wonder, if there is a shorter way...

Answer (score 0):

Insert -> Equation, type the equation.

Hightlight the character or string that need to be a subscript,

Format -> subscript

Comment: Subscript or superscript is not highlighted inside an equation. Instead, highlight the characters ->go to Equation -> ex Script as shown above -> Subscripts to edit .